# What do you call the plastic bit that mounts brake cable housing to dedicated frame mounting spots?

Tags: cable, cable-housing

[image]

I lost a couple and have no idea what to search for online.

Comment: Looks like a "shim" to me.

Comment: Clarify please - this is for hydraulic hose as pictured, or for outers of cable-actuated lines?

Comment: Clarified the question. Was referring to brake cable housing. The picture is of 5mm brake cable housing, not a hydraulic hose.

Answer (score 8):

Jagwire calls these ["Hose Guide for Frame Loops"](https://jagwire.com/products/small-parts/cable-stops).

I've also found these under ["Cable Guide"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AWBG7HM) on Amazon.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across them at https://www.kineticbikebearings.com/kbb9038-slotted-cable-guide-pack-qty-20.html, called **Slotted Cable Guides** or slotted (wedge type) cable guide.

The term slotted might help disambiguate from other search results.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are possibly called "cable clamps". For most frames that I've seen, they looked like this:

[image: Clamps]

When lost, they are usually replaced by zip-ties, which are a better solution in the first place, from my perspective.

Your frame, however, looks to use a different type of clamps which act like inserts. From the picture it is hard to tell whether the regular U-shaped clamps will work for you. For them to work, you need matching holes in the cable stop/guide, e.g.:

[image: Cable stop]

A zip-tie around the tube will definitely work in your case, but it won't be equally aesthetically pleasing to look at, to be honest.

Comment: This is mainly a kind of housing 'widener'. The purpose is basically to prevent the housing from rattling in the retaining clamps. Other than that, it has no functional purpose. The ones on the second picture in the answer have the advantage of removing cable friction because of the free running cable.